# URL scheme for opening native calendar with specific date

Tags: objective-c, cocoa-touch, calendar, icalendar

I have found the sample code to open calendar from my app, but i can't open at a specific date.

```
NSString* launchUrl = @"calshow://";
[[UIApplication sharedApplication] openURL:[NSURL URLWithString: launchUrl]];
```

Is there a way to add specific date at the end of the "lunchUrl" string so when the user opens the calendar it displays the given date.

I have already tried the following formats: @"calshow://?=2013 12 19", @"calshow://?=2013-12-19", @"calshow://?=2013+12+19". None of these seem to work for me... any ideas what am i'm doing wrong?

Answer (score 30, accepted):

I played with this url scheme a little and found the way to do it. The main two points are:

1. Don't use "//" after the `calshow:`
2. Pass timestamp since reference date (1 Jan 2001)

Here is the code:

```
- (void)showCalendarOnDate:(NSDate *)date
{
    // calc time interval since 1 January 2001, GMT
    NSInteger interval = [date timeIntervalSinceReferenceDate]; 
    NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"calshow:%ld", interval]];
    [[UIApplication sharedApplication] openURL:url];
}
```

And this is how I call it:

```
// create some date and show the calendar with it
- (IBAction)showCalendar:(id)sender
{
    NSDateComponents *comps = [[NSDateComponents alloc] init];
    [comps setDay:4];
    [comps setMonth:7];
    [comps setYear:2010];

    NSCalendar *cal = [[NSCalendar alloc] initWithCalendarIdentifier:NSGregorianCalendar];

    [self showCalendarOnDate:[cal dateFromComponents:comps]];
}
```

Perhaps you should take into account that `calshow:` is not a public url scheme, so maybe Apple would frown upon using it in this way. Or maybe they wouldn't (I haven't researched that).

Comment: Hi Andris, i have used above code, its working perfectly for past date. if i give future date it come back to current date. Can you please give some suggestion for opent the future date.

Comment: is this possible to get date from above default calendar?

Answer (score 5):

For react native with momentjs:

```
const testDate = moment('2020–04–01'),      // date is local time
  referenceDate = moment.utc('2001–01-01'), // reference date is utc
  seconds = testDate.unix() — referenceDate.unix();
Linking.openURL('calshow:' + seconds); //opens cal to April 1 2020
```

https://medium.com/@duhseekoh/need-to-open-the-os-calendar-at-a-specific-date-in-react-native-55f3a085cf8e

Answer (score 3):

This works on ios 8 - just add seconds since 00:00 1 Jan 2001, so to open cal on 2 Jan 2001

```
NSString* launchUrl = @"calshow:86400";
[[UIApplication sharedApplication] openURL:[NSURL URLWithString: launchUrl]];
```

I'm using RubyMotion, so my code looks something like this:

```
url = NSURL.URLWithString("calshow:#{my_date - Time.new(2001,1,1)}")
UIApplication.sharedApplication.openURL(url)
```

Answer (score 3):

**Swift 3**

```
UIApplication.shared.openURL(URL(string: "calshow:\(date.timeIntervalSinceReferenceDate)")!)
```

Comments on whether Apple allows to use this would be appreciated!