# How to open default iPhone calendar for given specific date from app?

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, calendar

I use to open the default iPhone calendar from my app using the following code,

```
[[UIApplication sharedApplication] openURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"calshow://"]];
```

But i would like to open calendar from a specified date. Is it possible to open specified date in iPhone calendar from application? **Also i need to open the future date**. Please suggest me some idea about this.

Comment: possible duplicate of [URL scheme for opening native calendar with specific date](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20684038/url-scheme-for-opening-native-calendar-with-specific-date)

Comment: @rahul_send89 i used that but for future date it just come back to current date... so how can i set for future date?