# URL scheme for opening native calendar with specific event id

Tags: ios, ekcalendar

At first, I knew there is no public APIs for this approach.

---

Tapping an event from iOS8 native calendar widget launches calendar with specific event. So, I can guess that there must be a URL scheme for it. Because widget and calendar works on each sand box, So, the `NSURL` must be used.

---

I found a some clues from [iPhoneDevWiki.net](http://iphonedevwiki.net/index.php/NSURL).
It says that `calshow:x?eventid=id` is an URL scheme that opens specific event, and it is used by `SpringBoard`.

Since the value of the `id` param is not described clear,
So, I have tested this url scheme with:

- `EKEvent.calendarItemIdentifier`
- `EKEvent.externalCalendarItemIdentifier`
- `EKEvent.eventIdentifier`

None of them did work.

The wiki may be outdated.

Is there anyone who could opens or reveal the specific event with native calendar?

---

And I found another clue from [similar questions in Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20684038/url-scheme-for-opening-native-calendar-with-specific-date).

The `calshow:` scheme.

It seems to used for open calendar with specific date. It can be used as `calshow:[time interval since reference date]`, the reference date seems to 1/1/2001

It can be used to reveal an event rather than opens it. However, when the calendar is not running on background, This approach also not works.

---

And I also found that the `x-apple-calevent` scheme can launches calendar also , But I don't know the details(path and params) at all.

---

Any clues and opinions will be welcomed.

Best Regars.

Comment: Have you find any solution to this ?

Comment: I'd also be interested in a solution, if you found one. I know it's possible to open a specific event in Calendar.app, because Omnifocus does it, but I also wasn't able to get it to work with the properties you mentioned. I think  it's the url scheme that must be different...

Comment: hey @jeeeyul did you find any solution? i do have same problem [here](http://stackoverflow.com/q/39846024/3308174)

Answer (score 0):

I've been able to use the `calshow:x?eventid=id` scheme by

- provide a timestamp (seconds) since reference date (Jan 2001) for `x`
- provide a numeric value for `eventid`

---

I've been able to open event details on a simulator using these arguments `calshow:685409700?eventid=99`.

[image: iPhone Simulator showing System Calendar - Event View]

As you can see date information is inferred from the `timestamp` and in this case  is incorrectly showing that Thanksgiving is on Sep 21st

Lower `eventid` like `1`, `2`, up to at least `20` open contact related information, for example using `calshow:685409700?eventid=1` brings this up

[image: iPhone Simulator showing contact information]

---

Using non numeric IDs or numbers higher than 200 doesn't seem to work and they just open the Day View for the specific timestamp

The `eventid` parameter seems to use some numeric indexing and not actual event/calendar item identifiers

I've accidentally managed to make the url scheme match something, because the `id` I tried to use started with `16`, so I guess it was parsed to the number `16`

I've also been able to match some of the events created from my app by using `eventid` between `100` and `150`

Other than that I have no clue about what `id` the `eventid` is being mapped to