# add event to iphone calendar

Tags: ios, objective-c, calendar, ekeventkit

I'm Using SAcalendar.
this is my json:

```
{-data: - [
- {
id: "1",
event_start: "2014-06-09 11:30",
event_end: "2014-06-09 12:30",
title: "Click a date to create a new event and drag to change its     date and time. Click on an existing event to modify. Click "Show Standard     Settings" to set additional event properties."
},
- {
id: "2",
event_start: "2017-01-03 16:30",
event_end: "2017-01-03 17:30",
title: "fgdgf"
},
- {
id: "3",
event_start: "2017-01-11 03:30",
event_end: "2017-01-11 06:00",
title: "fdfgdg"
},    ]}
```

now i want to add these event into my calendar
 This is my code(same code of using EventKit)

```
EKEventStore *store = [[EKEventStore alloc] init];
[store requestAccessToEntityType:EKEntityTypeEvent completion:^(BOOL     granted, NSError *error) {
if (!granted) { return; }
EKEvent *event = [EKEvent eventWithEventStore:store];
event.title = @"Event Title";
event.startDate = [NSDate date]; //today
event.endDate = [event.startDate dateByAddingTimeInterval:60*60];  //set 1 hour meeting
[event setCalendar:[store defaultCalendarForNewEvents]];
NSError *err = nil;
[store saveEvent:event span:EKSpanThisEvent commit:YES error:&err];
NSString *savedEventId = event.eventIdentifier;  //this is so you can access this event later
```

it doest's display any events.
i am new in ios,please help..
thanks in advance.

Comment: Waht is your error?

Comment: Display Nothing..

Comment: is &err nil when you set a brekapoint at savedEventId?

Comment: thanks for response,
//http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41691269/when-use-click-on-particular-date-a-alert-will-show-with-that-event-title
plz check this for same question but different logic

Comment: please check [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/q/39846024/3308174) with code that works to save event on iPhone calendar