# when user click on particular date a alert will show with that event title

Tags: ios, objective-c, calendar, uialertview, ekeventkit

I'm Using SAcalendar.
this is my json:

```
data: - [
- {
id: "1",
event_start: "2014-06-09 11:30",
event_end: "2014-06-09 12:30",
title: "Click a date to create a new event and drag to change its date and time. Click on an existing event to modify. Click "Show Standard Settings" to set additional event properties."
},
- {
id: "2",
event_start: "2017-01-03 16:30",
event_end: "2017-01-03 17:30",
title: "fgdgf"
},
- {
id: "3",
event_start: "2017-01-11 03:30",
event_end: "2017-01-11 06:00",
title: "fdfgdg"
},]}
```

now when user click on particular date A alert will show with that event title.
this is my logic

```
-(void) SACalendar:(SACalendar*)calendar didSelectDate:(int)day month:(int)month year:(int)year
{

for(int i=0; i<EventArray.count; i++)
{
if([[EventArray objectAtIndex:i]objectForKey:@"event_start"] && [[EventArray objectAtIndex:i]objectForKey:@"event_end"])
    {
     eventtitlestring = [[EventArray objectAtIndex:i] objectForKey:@"title"];

    if(event_startString==eventtitlestring && event_endString==eventtitlestring)
    {
        UIAlertView *showevent = [[UIAlertView alloc]initWithTitle:@"Alert" message:self.eventtitlestring delegate:nil cancelButtonTitle:@"Ok" otherButtonTitles:nil];
        [showevent show];
    }
    }
}
```

plz help me with right logic
i am new in ios,please help..
thanks in advance.

Comment: Why you have added for loop here?

Comment: Why are you comparing `event_start` which is a date string with `event_title`?

Comment: eventtitlestring is string with "title" show json..

Comment: because this delegate method of SACalendar  "Delegate method : get called when a date is selected"@User511

Comment: this is my logic, i am new in ios so my logic is weak, plz u suggest that what should i do?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From what I see in the question. In understood it as follows. You need to compare the selected date in calendar with dates given in json. If it matches, then you have to show the alert. For that, you need to compare the selected date with dates given in Json.

Inside the function,

```
-(void) SACalendar:(SACalendar*)calendar didSelectDate:(int)day month:(int)month year:(int)year
{

   NSDateFormatter *dateFormatter = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];          
   dateFormatter.dateFormat = @"yyyy-MM-dd";
   dateFormatter.timeZone = [NSTimeZone systemTimeZone];

    for(int i=0; i < EventArray.count; i++)
    {
        NSString *eventStartString = [[EventArray objectAtIndex:i] objectForKey:@"event_start"];
        NSString *eventEndString = [[EventArray objectAtIndex:i]objectForKey:@"event_end"];

        if(eventStartString != nil && eventEndString != nil)
        {// s_ -> start; e_ -> end;
            eventStartString = [eventStartString substringToIndex:10];
            eventEndString = [eventEndString substringToIndex:10];

            NSDate *s_date = [dateFormatter dateFromString:eventStartString];
            NSDate *e_date = [dateFormatter dateFromString:eventEndString]

            NSCalendar *myCalendar = [NSCalendar currentCalendar];

            long s_day = [myCalendar component:NSCalendarUnitDay fromDate:s_date];
            long s_month = [myCalendar component:NSCalendarUnitMonth fromDate:s_date];
            long s_year = [myCalendar component:NSCalendarUnitYear fromDate:s_date];

            long e_day = [myCalendar component:NSCalendarUnitDay fromDate:e_date];
            long e_month = [myCalendar component:NSCalendarUnitMonth fromDate:e_date];
            long e_year = [myCalendar component:NSCalendarUnitYear fromDate:e_date];

            eventtitlestring = [[EventArray objectAtIndex:i] objectForKey:@"title"];

            if ((day == (int)s_day) && (month == (int)s_month) && (year == (int)s_year)) {
                UIAlertView *showevent = [[UIAlertView alloc]initWithTitle:@"Alert" message:self.eventtitlestring delegate:nil cancelButtonTitle:@"Ok" otherButtonTitles:nil];
                [showevent show];
                return;
            }else if ((day == (int)e_day) && (month == (int)e_month) && (year == (int)e_year)) {
                UIAlertView *showevent = [[UIAlertView alloc]initWithTitle:@"Alert" message:self.eventtitlestring delegate:nil cancelButtonTitle:@"Ok" otherButtonTitles:nil];
                [showevent show];
                return;
            }
        }
    }        
}
```

After extracting month, day, year, you can compare them and accordingly show the event

Comment: getting this error
    -[NSCalendar component:fromDate:]: date cannot be nil
Future exception.
A few of these errors are going to be reported with this complaint, then further violations will simply be ignored.
Here is the backtrace where this occurred this time (some frames may be missing due to compiler optimizations):
    s_day  returning nil;

Comment: Let me check and get back to you

Comment: also dateFormatter is "yyyy-mm-dd" plz note.

Comment: madam u rock... done,
 i just changed dateFormatter.dateFormat = @"yyyy-MM-DD HH:mm"; in old one..

Comment: Thank You mam,
really u r genius :)