# React Native How can I Link to Calendar iOS and Android?

Tags: android, ios, calendar, react-native, icalendar

My react-native App needs to be able to put calendar entries into the device calendar app.  On the web version we call a https resource and the browser takes care of the rest.

Is there a Linking API on react-native for iCal files?
Is there a common ios and android solution?

```
e.g.
<OpenURLButton url={'ical://www.example.com/calendar/event.ical'} />
```

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure if there's a cross platform URL scheme for calendars, but you can use the `Linking` API for this purpose which is available both on iOS and Android:

```
import { Linking } from 'react-native';
Linking.openURL('ical://www.example.com/calendar/event.ical');
```

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately there is no ical:// style URL scheme you can use. The undocumented [calshow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20684038/url-scheme-for-opening-native-calendar-with-specific-date) will allow you to show the calendar at a specific date/time, but not add events automatically. You can also open a `.ics` file using the [Linking](http://facebook.github.io/react-native/releases/0.27/docs/linking.html) API that @oblador mentioned, which will allow you to subscribe to events from that file as a new calendar, but won't do anything nice like open the "New Event" dialog. The closest I could find was the [React Native Calendar Events](http://react-components.com/component/react-native-calendar-events) module, which will help you programmatically add calendar events, but only on iOS at the moment.

Comment: Thanks Adrian, I have used the Linking option for now.  Am very interested in seeing this develop into a good functional cross reference API... fingers crossed.