# URL to open native Apple Calendar app on any device?

Tags: url, hyperlink, icalendar

Is there a way to create a url link that can be inserted into a pdf or email that will open any user's Apple Calendar app to a specific date and/or time?

I've seen the webcal:// URI but I cannot seem to find specifics on how to create a usable link.

Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

I use "calshow://" to open the calendar app

here's more info to add parameters : [URL scheme for opening native calendar with specific date](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20684038/url-scheme-for-opening-native-calendar-with-specific-date)